# Data not getting saved using RMS

Tags: java-me, emulation, rms

In my j2me app, I write data using this:

```
RecordStore rs = RecordStore.openRecordStore("mydb", true);
String buf = "Some text";
rs.addRecord(buf.getBytes(), 0, buf.getBytes().length);
rs.closeRecordStore();
```

The data stays as long as the app is running, but when I restart the app, there is no "mydb"

I tested it on emulator and device both. I know there can be some problems in emulator but it should work on the device at least.

I'm using:
Java Me SDK 3.0
CLDC 1.1
MIDP 2.0
Device: Samsung S5620
OS:Vista

Is it related to some permissions or the app should be signed before running?

Comment: Have you closed your application correctyl? Try Midlet.notifyDestroyed(); to end your application.